# Get Starting and Ending X-Y Cordinate of Textview in Android

Tags: android, coordinates

How can I find out Starting and Ending Co-Ordinates of Textview in Android? As Shown in below image?

[image]

I am trying with this [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/error-of-getlocationinwindow-and.html)

Using method

```
getLocationInWindow (int[] location)
getLocationOnScreen (int[] location)
```

but not get proper result..

Any help will be appreciated.. Thanks :)

Comment: What do you want the coordinates to be relative to? The parent view or the app's screen?

Comment: top,left,bottom,right this will give the bounds based on the parent where the view remains.

Answer (score 2):

Let x1 and y1 are start cordinates of text view then its values would be:

```
   TextView textview = (TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.textview1);

   int x1=textview.getLeft();  
   int y1=textview.getTop();
```

Let x2 and y2 are end cordinates of text view then its values would be:

```
   int x2=textview.getRight();
   int y2=textview.getBottom();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the coordinates to be root-relative (ie. (0,0) is the top-left pixel of the app's window), you need to do the following:

```
    private Rect getScreenXY(Context context, View view, View rootView) {
        int[] coords = new int[2];
        // This returns the screen-space location of the upper left corner of the view
        view.getLocationOnScreen(coords);

        // This rect is relative to the screen
        Rect rootRelativeRect = new Rect(coords[0], coords[1], view.getWidth() + coords[0], view.getHeight() + coords[1]);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        // To get root-relative coordinates we need to add the status bar's height
        rootRelativeRect.offset(0, rootView.getMeasuredHeight() - displayMetrics.heightPixels);

        return rootRelativeRect;
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, the other solucions works when they are in the root View and no in nested views

Answer (score 0):

getX() + getWidth() is your end X coordinate, getY() + getHeight() is your end Y coordinate